# How to create Unicode version of user32.dll - functions in Team developer

Tags: guptateamdeveloper, centura

Since  the sdk menu functions *GetMenu, CreatePopupMenu,
InsertMenuA , AppendMenuA* etc are not working properly in  6.2 Version.  I think Unicode version  of above functions may
works fine in version 6.2.

Comment: Any Windows SDK function ending with an 'A' should be replaced with its UNICODE counterpart ending in 'W' , if running TeamDeveloper v5 onwards. Note that the parameter list may be different.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Any Windows SDK function ending with an 'A' should be replaced with its UNICODE counterpart ending in 'W' , if running TeamDeveloper v5 onwards. Note that the parameter list may be different. You don't have to 'create' them, - they already exist , so just need replacing.

Comment: Go here : http://samples.tdcommunity.net/index.php?dir=WinApi32/ to get a full list of Win32 UNICODE version of Win API's. Specifically, download 'WinApi_Declarations_v110.zip'